# VB.net Office Solution - Accessing value in named Range in a Worksheet

Tags: vb.net, office-interop, excel-2010

I'm working on converting an Excel VBA project to a VB.net Office Solution.  In VBA accessing a named range within a sheet was pretty easy.
    Sheet1.Range("NamedRange")
would give you the value in that cell.

In VB.net I've tried several different things, all ending in failure.

I started here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168292(v=office.11).aspx#excelobj_link9

I'm using one of the Visual Studio Excel 2010 Document template, and I managed to set a value in a named range on a sheet.  The template creates a class for each tab on the worksheet, so I was able to do this.

```
Me.Range("A5").Value
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to access a range on a worksheet, in particular I can't figure out what objects I need to create before I can access a worksheet.  The following is what does not work:)

```
Public Sub GetInputs()
    Dim XlSheet1 As Excel.Worksheets
    Xlval = XlSheet1("Sheet1").Range("NamedRange").Value
```

This leaves me with null reference...  I've tried several other things and gotten several other errors.  Any push in the correct direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code compiles and runs in a separate code module.  The key is using the Globals object to access the Excel application objects:

```
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlNamedRange As Excel.Range
Dim xlVal As Object

xlWorksheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
xlNamedRange = xlWorksheet.Range("NamedRange")
xlVal = xlNamedRange.Value
MessageBox.Show(xlVal)
```

Comment: That worked,thanks! I had one additional problem, I had renamed the tab on my Worksheet, and forgot to change Sheet1 to the correct Worksheet name in my code.  :(