# Edit Value In Excel Range

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with values in a range which I want to perform some calculations on in vb.net. I pass that range to vb.net using COM. When I try editing the values of the range, nothing happens.

My question seems to be very similar to these questions, but I can't quite figure out what step I am missing.

[How to edit cell value in VB.net - Using .Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17854317/how-to-edit-cell-value-in-vb-net-using-interop-excel)
[VB.net Office Solution - Accessing value in named Range in a Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266012/vb-net-office-solution-accessing-value-in-named-range-in-a-worksheet)

VBA CODE:

```
Function MyTestRange (Byref myrng as range)

   Set classLib = New VBProject.CClass
   MyTestRange = classLib.MyTestRange(myrng)

End Function
```

VB.NET code

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class CClass
    Function MyTestRange(ByRef myrng As Range) As Double
     Dim newrng As Range
     Dim b As Integer = myrng.Rows.Count
     Dim i As Integer

     newrng = myrng
     For i = 1 To b
         newrng.Value2(i, 1) = myrng.Value2(i, 1) + 1
     Next i
     MyTestRange = newrng.Value2(1, 1)
    End Function
End class
```

While this code doesn't generate an error, it doesn't change the values in newrng.

Edit:

I have tried many iterations based on the link provide, but always get the same error :

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

This is the simplest way to generate the error:

```
    Dim c As Object

    c = myrng.Value
    myrng.Value = c
```

Hence amending the values to something new, seems out of reach!

Edit 2:

After chatting with user Mat's Mug, I tried to edit a value in a range, purely in VBA.

This sub works perfectly:

```
Sub rangesub()
 Dim example As Range
 Set example = Range("A1:A4")
 example.Value = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
End Sub
```

Excel functions also seem able to handle passing ranges:

```
Function SimpleCopyRange(myrng)
 SimpleCopyRange = myrng
End Function
```

A very simple combination of this code works:

```
Function EditRange(myrng)
 Dim example As Range
 Set example = Range("A1:A4")
 EditRange = example
End Function
```

However there is an unspecified error if I try to edit the range:

```
Function EditRange(myrng)
 Dim example As Range
 Set example = Range("A1:A4")
 example.Value = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4))
 EditRange = example
End Function
```

The application.transpose part obviously adds a layer of complexity, and can be replaced with example.Value = 8 without any changes in results.

Comment: In your code, in this line `newrng = myrng` all you do is assigning same data to a different pointer. It is not a new range. This is same old range. So, all you do is increment number but it will be same in the new ad old range

Comment: How can I modify myrng (or make a proper copy and modify that)? myrng.Value2(i, 1) = myrng.Value2(i, 1) + 1 doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't think you can even create "new range". Range is something you select in worksheet. Here is the answer for your trouble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811664/set-cell-value-using-excel-interop

Comment: Edited question @T.S. , but still not able to get a useful result based on that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this question/answer:

[Excel VBA: Iterating over range parameter and change cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12734949/excel-vba-iterating-over-range-paramter-and-change-cell-values)

It appears that a UDF can only change the calling cell.

I think therefore this method is impossible.

The workaround is to to rewrite the code to work with an array, assign the range to an array, edit the array and pass it to the new function.